Previous work info for DS160 if I worked on my startup in the past which was unregistered?
Here is my employment record:
2019-2022(Jan) : Worked as Software Engineer for a company
2022(Feb) - 2023(Feb) : Worked on my own startup with 3 co-founders. The startup was not registered as a company.
2023(Mar) - Current : Working as Software Engineer for a company
While filling my DS160, does the startup counts as employment. And if yes, what do I mention as employer name, address and supervisor name.
I don't want to skip this info because then it would leave an unexplained gap in my employment record.
Please help.
Thanks.

Self Employed. When you work on your business it’s typically self employment. I feel they should add the category Startup

@SaranshSharma There is no option to select the employment type for previous work exp. That option is only available for present employment.
In the previous work section, there is directly an option to submit employer name, address and other details.

There is you have to specify using dates and you can put your friends name who you worked with as a co founder
